# How do I get moment-timezone to always baseline against the provided timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

My code is as follows:

```
const moment = require("moment-timezone");
moment("2018-01-01").tz("Australia/Sydney");
```

With Sydney as the local timezone, I get:

`moment.parseZone("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+11:00")`

But if Sydney is not the local timezone, I get (as an example):

`moment.parseZone("2018-01-01T11:00:00.000+11:00")`

(note 11:00:00 instead of 00:00:00)

How do I change my code to get the same (Sydney) result irrespective of local timezone?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, what you need is `set()`. You can set the time values as you want.

For example:

```
const sydney = moment('2018-01-01').tz('Europe/London').set({hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, millisecond: 0}).format();
```

Let me know if this help you

You can see the docs here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/